# How to render the missing data series and fix the dates on the x-axis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, data-visualization, linechart

I am trying to re-create the same line chart that is seen below using the `Highcharts` library. I can't figure out how can I display the date on the `x-axis` the same way it is shown on the image, and also why my third data series is not getting displayed?

[image]

Here's my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/271gxvuL/1/

```
xAxis: {
      crosshair: true,
      title: { text: 'Date' },
      categories: ['Jan 04', 'Jan 11', 'Jan 18', 'Jan 25'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    },
    yAxis: {
      tickInterval: 10,
      min: 5,
      max: 40,
      title: {
        text: '# of Shares (mm)'
      },
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0
    },
    legend: {
      title: { text: 'Option Series' },
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'GME Call',
      color: "#00429d",
      data: [18.40345395, 18.32595087, 19.15087983, 19.16410026, 18.55687485, 20.95533447, 20.4068335, 30.04684925, 33.73630533, 32.00319773, 20.66296168, 20.77395832, 23.55373851, 38.30826413, 29.98265297, 34.92300725, 32.19425239, 28.27697149, 31.92597248],
      marker: { enabled: false },
      label: { enabled: false }
    }, {
      name: 'GME Net',
      color: "#009c56",
      data: [3.981667259, 3.699835889, 5.707331914, 5.583661701, 4.031818851, 9.716787874, 8.218344693, 24.91298209, 29.72145703, 27.10696218, 15.76613521, 15.21344769, 18.31385242, 33.94138296, 24.14691476, 30.91437069, 30.15361859, 24.33123219, 29.52458396],
      marker: { enabled: false },
      label: { enabled: false }
    }, {
      name: 'GME Put',
      color: "#f79646",
      data: [-14.42178669, -14.62611498, -13.44354791, -13.58043856, -14.525056, -11.2385466, -12.18848881, -5.133867153, -4.014848306, -4.896235549, -4.896826466, -5.560510629, -5.239886084, -4.366881175, -5.835738209, -4.00863656, -2.040633802, -3.945739308, -2.401388521],
      marker: { enabled: false },
      label: { enabled: false }
    }],
```

Comment: your 3rd serie is below 0 and min for  yAxis is 5. thus it is not visible. Concerning Xaxis (Dates) if you want to make same ones then you should pass all the data in categories option not only 4 values

Comment: you can check http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/1cvx3ujt/ might it will be usefull fro your task

Comment: Thank you @Asturion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to change your data into the array of arrays, where nested array includes the x date format, something like:

> [[ x date in miliseconds, y value]]

2. You can use the pointStart & pointInterval features:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointInterval

3. You can define wanted a array of categories that you want to display on the xAxis - just like is done in your example

Comment: Thank you Sebastian